# Observable Array UI not being updated when an item is changed

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

this is inside my view model.

```
self.Notifications = ko.observableArray(); // loaded by ajax

self.MarkAsFlagged = function(item) { //updates the item in Notifications
        console.log('MarkAsFlagged');
        var index = self.Notifications.indexOf(item);
        console.log(index);

        var flagStatus = item.Flagged; // current flagstatus
        item.Flagged = !flagStatus; // set true if false and viceversa

        flagStatus = !flagStatus;// set true if false and viceversa
        self.Notifications.replace(self.Notifications()[index], item);
}
```

this is my html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Notifications "  >
 <li>
   <span data-bind="text: Name" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>       
   <div style="float: right; width:15px;">
       <input type="image" id="" data-bind="click:function(){$parent.MarkAsFlagged($data)},css: {flagged: Flagged==true, unFlagged: Flagged==false }" style='float:right;padding-right:3px;' />
   </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

when i click the `MarkedAsFlagged` and replace the item on `self.Notifications()` the ui is not changing.

the ui only responses when i remove any item from the array.
please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item props in Notifications array is not observable. So, when you change it in MarkAsFlagged, ui is not updated. You should create own model for item with observable props:

```
function ItemModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Flagged = ko.observable(data.Flagged);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Notifications = ko.observableArray();

    self.loadNotifications = function() {
       // loading data...

       var itemModels = _.map(data, function (item) {
           return new ItemModel(item);
       }); 
       ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.Notifications(), itemModels);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says "_" is not defined. i am using knockout 2.1 . is there anything missing?

Comment: thanks i used $.map and it is working. thanks very much

Comment: can u edit your answer, your self.loadNotifications() at last line must be a typo?

Comment: yep, it's a bug, i've changed to self.Notifications.